# How to clear all previous history activity in android?

Tags: android

Just example.

Ac1 : Signin -> Home
Ac2 : Signin -> Register -> Home

In Ac2, I would like to press back button in Home activity, and the display should show Android home screen. But, the actually, it displays Signin activity. 
How to clear Signin and Register activity in Ac2 after I go to Home activity.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

On the AndroidManifest.xml set :

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

For Signin and Register activities

Answer (score 1):

You can try finishing the activities you do not need any more right after calling startActivity.

```
startActivity(homeIntent);
this.finish();
```